# Regular expression match the begining and the end without the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I ***merge both*** those regular expressions? This is interesting because it would allow to match the **beginning** of a string and the **end** without touching the content in the **middle**.

```
function cleanURL(url) {
    url = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|ww\d\.|w\d\d\.)?/, '')
    url = url.replace(/(\/.*)/, '')
    return url
}

console.log(cleanURL('https://hello-world.example.tld/yello-blue/green'))
```

Result: `hello-world.example.tld`

Comment: `new URL("https://hello-world.example.tld/yello-blue/green").hostname` When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb.

Comment: Add it as an Answer, you're a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to use regex to tease out parts of URLs just use the `URL` class:

```
new URL("https://hello-world.example.tld/yello-blue/green").hostname
```

That doesn't mean it can't be done with a regex, you just need to look for whatever is between `//` and `/`.

All this said, I'm not sure what your actual intent is, because there's a bunch of shenanigans with `www` etc. The `URL` approach won't filter, it'll just return the hostname.